# Flathub packages font doesn’t work on RHEL 9

Tags: linux, fonts, gnome, fontconfig, flatpak

I have installed many packages from Flathub on my PC (RHEL 9) but many of these (g4music, Amberol, Color Picker, etc.) can't be displayed properly. See next pictures:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, these applications are unusable. So, I need your help to solve this problem.

Terminal output for g4music is next:

> Enable ReplayGain: false
> Enable Pipewire: false
> Found 696 songs in 0.004244 seconds
> Parse MP4 Error read_all
> (com.github.neithern.g4music:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:55:18.108: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'Cantarell Bold 9'
> (com.github.neithern.g4music:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:55:18.108: font_face status is: file not found
> (com.github.neithern.g4music:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:55:18.108: scaled_font status is: file not found
> (com.github.neithern.g4music:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:55:18.109: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'Cantarell Bold 9'
> (com.github.neithern.g4music:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:55:18.109: font_face status is: file not found
> (com.github.neithern.g4music:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:55:18.109: scaled_font status is: file not found
> (com.github.neithern.g4music:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:55:18.109: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'Cantarell 11'
> (com.github.neithern.g4music:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:55:18.109: font_face status is: file not found

Terminal output for Color Picker is next:

> (gcolor3:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:58:35.707: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'Cantarell 11'
> (gcolor3:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:58:35.707: font_face status is: file not found
> (gcolor3:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:58:35.707: scaled_font status is: file not found
> (gcolor3:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:58:35.708: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'Cantarell 11'
> (gcolor3:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:58:35.708: font_face status is: file not found
> (gcolor3:2): Pango-WARNING **: 20:58:35.708: scaled_font status is: file not found
> ** (gcolor3:2): WARNING **: 20:58:35.712: Cannot count number of items: Key file does not have group “Colors”

It seems there's a problem with fonts but I don't have experience with this topic.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many test, to resolve this issue I followed next steps:

1. Install Cairo fonts using "Font Downloader" application. This will
   install fonts to ***~/.local/share/fonts***
2. Copy next fonts from
   ***/usr/share/fonts*** to ***~/.local/share/fonts***

- cantarell/*
- dejavu-sans-fonts/*
- dejavu-sans-mono-fonts/*
- dejavu-serif-fonts/*

That's all. Enjoy your flatpak apps.

[image]

[image]